# What is the length-of-stay limit?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My mother-in-law has a Chinese (PRC) passport and the USA visa shows an expiration date about 10 years in the future. There is nothing about a per-visit time limit.  The entry stamp shows “Class/Until” with “B2” written in pen.

How do I find out the actual rules?

Answer (score 9):

B-1 and B-2 visitors normally get six months each time they enter, but that should be indicated explicitly by a date on the entry stamp.  This is the meaning of the word "until" on the stamp: that is the place where they are supposed to write or stamp the date by which the traveler must leave the United States.

If they fail to put a date on the passport stamp, you can look up the record in the I-94 database at [i94.cbp.dhs.gov](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov).

In some circumstances, the immigration inspector may grant a shorter period of admission.  It is of course also possible to be refused admission, but something would have to be obviously amiss for that to happen.